# How to show all images from a folder in Xamarin Cross-Platform app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I am using VS 2017 to create a cross platform (UWP, Android, iOS) Xamarin app. I am trying to show all images from a folder on device as thumbnails (similar to gallery app, sample screenshot attached). 
[image: Sample image from Xamarin website]

I have looked into `WrapLayout` sample code provided on Xamarin website ([Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/CustomLayout/WrapLayout/)), but it's loading all images from internet using JSON

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            var images = await GetImageListAsync();
            foreach (var photo in images.Photos)
            {
                var image = new Image
                {
                    Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(photo + string.Format("?width={0}&height={0}&mode=max", Device.OnPlatform(240, 240, 120))))
                };
                wrapLayout.Children.Add(image);
            }
        }

        async Task<ImageList> GetImageListAsync()
        {
            var requestUri = "https://docs.xamarin.com/demo/stock.json";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var result = await client.GetStringAsync(requestUri);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImageList>(result);
            }
        }
```

I have also looked into `Xamarin Media Plugin` ([Link](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)), but it shows only one image at a time. Sample code -

```
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

    if (file == null)
        return;
    MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        file.Dispose();
        return stream;
    });
```

**But I am unable to find a way to implement these two (or any other methods) in such a way that I can create my own gallery section in my app.**

Comment: Hello, were you able to find a way to accomplish this? I'd appreciate any insight

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Activity in your specific platform. This activity will be launched as an intent throught your PCL project using, for instance, Dependency Services.
In this custom Activity you should have a GridView which fills its source from the current directory if the file fits your restrictions, such a specific extension, size, etc.

Finally, to get the selected image you just send the image path or whatever you need to the PCL project with DependencyService.